# UNIX:Two directories with same name on the same path?

Tags: unix, path, directory

While I was going through a unix system I found Five, two directories with same name listed on the same path, when I did a `ls -Dl`

Here is the view, Why I said Five, Two Directories with same name.....

```
//11/# ls -Dl

total 553

drwxrwxr-x  2 root      root          12288 Dec 20  2010 bin

drwxrwxr-x  2 root      root          16384 Sep 28  2010 bin

drwxrwxr-x 11 root      root           4096 Oct 25 06:49 etc

drwxrwxr-x 11 root      root           8192 May 17 07:40 etc

drwxrwxr-x  3 root      root           4096 Sep 28  2010 qnx4

drwxrwxr-x  4 root      root           4096 Jul 26  2010 qnx4

drwxrwxr--  4 root      root           4096 Sep 28  2010 registry

drwxrwxr-x  4 root      root           4096 Aug 31  2008 registry

drwxrwxr-x 16 root      root           4096 Sep 28  2010 usr

drwxrwxr-x 17 root      root           4096 May 27 03:49 usr
```

How can this be possible?? what will happen if I cd any one of them, which directory i'll end up in??

There is another way of looking at it, when I did `ls -liF` the directories listed here came up with different inodes. and were not even symbolic links or anything.???

Please explain this to me??

Comment: Have you checked your Filesystem? To find out the behaviour of cd you could cd in and check the inode number of . to see where you ended up.

Comment: what if you `ls -B`? This will print non-printable characters

Comment: Even if i end up going into one of the directory and figure out the inode of the directory and know which directory i m in, still i dont have the contents of the second directory. @user2859193

Comment: B is not a valid option on this system. @TomasCamin

Comment: @user2922452 check `man ls` there should be an option to print non-printables. Maybe `-b`?

Comment: i already did that....my system shows an option -Q for such purposes and prints a"?" at non-printable locales. but it wont show any non-printable characters in the names of these directories. @TomasCamin

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 12):

You should use all these commands to check what are various characters (including hidden ones) in your filename:

```
printf "[%s]\n" *

printf "%s\n" * | cat -vte

printf "%s\n" * | od -bc
```

Last one will also dump each dump each character in octal and ascii.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the last command allowed me to see that the two directories had the same name but used different casing (ex. "ABc" and "ABC") even though `ls` was showing them as the same name: "ABC"

Answer (score 4):

use `ls -b`, if you found any "\" appended after your folders or files, that should be spaces.

Answer (score -1):

In each pair, one directory name likely contains an unprintable character.  Try using mv to move both of them to unique file names.  One you shouldn't be able to name fully, and then you can specify it using a wildcard.

You should be able to rename one by just typing the filename, so you can temporarily rename it with "mv".  The other, which you probably want to get rid of, will be the one you need to specify by wildcard.  Try that.

Comment: even if i Write "mv usr xyz" How willl i know which usr the system is selecting.... @sdanzig