# How are two folders of the same name being created, and how do I remove it?

Tags: php, ubuntu, server

I am running ubuntu server version 16.4.04. I have a php script that does this:

```
if (!file_exists($directory)){
    mkdir($directory);
}
```

However, somehow an additional folder of the same name is created, except with an appended backslash `\`, which is only visible using the `dir` command, and not `ls`. Any attempts to `unlink directory\\` just return `No such file or directory "directory\"`. I'm not sure how it is getting created, or how to remove it.

```
alan@JohnstonHost:~/www/lmp/user_transactions$ ls -b
alan  alan\
alan@JohnstonHost:~/www/lmp/user_transactions$ unlink alan\\
unlink: cannot unlink 'alan\': No such file or directory
alan@JohnstonHost:~/www/lmp/user_transactions$
```

Dir results:

```
alan alan\
```

ll -a results:

```
total 16

drwxrwxrwx 4 alan     alan     4096 Apr 26 23:23 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 alan     alan     4096 Feb 28 11:25 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 26 23:32 alan/
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  1 21:04 alan /
```

Comment: could you append  `dir`  and  `ll -a` results to there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNIX:Two directories with same name on the same path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604384/unixtwo-directories-with-same-name-on-the-same-path)

Comment: qskane I have added the results to the question. As you can probably guess, the directory in question is `alan`

Comment: those aren't the same directory names.

Comment: Daniel, you'll have to help me out here. I say they are the "same" because they are spawned from the same php command `mkdir('alan');`
I am also incapable of deleting the alan\ folder, and do not understand how it came to be in the first place.

Comment: The second one has a trailing space. `rmdir alan\<space>` or `rmdir "alan "` in quotes.  If PHP created that and `$directory` is from some user input, you should `trim()` it before creating anything in the filesystem. If you are not otherwise validating it, you should ensure it meets your parameters for directory creation and doesn't allow something worse like `../../../../alan` to attempt to write elsewhere on the filesystem.

Comment: Micheal, you're the best. If you will post this as an answer, I will be happy to classify it as the solution. Thanks so much!